# HttpWebRequest post issue after login

Tags: c#, post, authentication, webrequest

I am creating a tool which logs in on a site and then posts a blogpost.

All the forms have a content Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

I use the following code to log in:

```
private void btnSignOn_Click_1(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string strURL = "http://en.netlog.com/go/login";
            HttpWebRequest HWRequest = GetRequest(strURL);
            Parameters HWParameters = ReadResponse(HWRequest, strURL);

            foreach (Parameter p in HWParameters) {
                switch (p.Name) {
                    case "nickname":
                        p.Value = txtHalfID.Text;
                        break;
                    case "password":
                        p.Value = txtHalfPassword.Text;
                        break;
                }
            }

            HWRequest = PostRequest(strURL, HWParameters, encURL);
            GetResponse(HWRequest);
        }
```

The string which was byte encoded and then written to the stream looks like this:

> action=login&target=-Lw_*&remember=YES&nickname=mynickname&password=mypassword&q=&referrer=home&action=login&target=-Lw*_&nickname=mynickname&password=mypassword&remember=YES&netlogVersion=v6.00

(the site has two login forms, one small one on the top and one in the middle of the page)

Next I press a button which is supposed to post a blog, I keep the cookies in a cookiecontainer and I can see when I check the webrequest that my profile is kept logged in.

The code for the blogpost is almost the same:

```
private void bntPostBlog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strURL = "http://en.netlog.com/go/manage/blog/view=add";
            HttpWebRequest HWRequest = GetRequest(strURL);
            Parameters HWParameters = ReadResponse(HWRequest, strURL);

            foreach (Parameter p in HWParameters) {
                p.Value = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p.Value);
                switch (p.Name) {
                    case "title":
                        p.Value = txtTitle.Text;
                        break;
                    case "message":
                        p.Value = txtMsg.Text;
                        break;
                }
            }

            HWRequest = PostRequest(strURL, HWParameters, encURL);
            GetResponse(HWRequest);
        }
```

This time the string looks like this:

> "q=&referrer=manage&title=testTitle&message=testMsg&action=__button&unSavedContentWarning=The+changes+in+your+blog+message+weren't+saved+yet.&csrftoken_add=3e16b204&allow_comments=YES&allow_ratings=YES&netlogVersion=v6.00"

However when I check the response I end up in the same "write blog" screen without a blog being posted.

At first I thought the problem was in the encoding of the string, hence the extra URLencode line in the blogpost click.

Does anyone recognize what I'm doing wrong? I don't see the difference between the blog post and the logon post. However only the logon works.

If u need more code I'd be happy to show it, I thought I'd keep it simpel by not posting all the functions..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you preformed a successful operation like this and checked it trough Fiddler so that you are positive that this is the post string?

Comment: You're right, I never checked on Fiddler, I found the problem in the string. It was just a wrong special character problem. Thanks!